# How to flushdb using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Is there a way to delete all keys in redis using stackexchange.redis?

I am trying to flush my redis database in my unit test setup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, it is on `IServer`.

For reasons and more information, please see [Where are `KEYS`, `SCAN`, `FLUSHDB` etc?](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan), which is linked from the project home page, under "Documentation":

[image]